# Python OGR Execute SQL - Get console output

Tags: python, ogr, invalid-data

I am currently trying to scan around 1500~ MapInfo TAB files for invalid geometry using Python and OGR.

So far, I've managed to run the following command to filter features that contain errors:

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("MapInfo File")
datasource = driver.Open(file, 0)
result = datasource.ExecuteSQL("select * from '" + file + "' WHERE not ST_IsValid(geometry)", dialect = "SQLITE")
```

Interestingly, when the SQL query is running I get outputs to the terminal (despite not using a print command) as follows:

```
Warning 1: Self-intersection at or near point 419991.27111455891 422299.0516533262
Warning 1: Self-intersection at or near point 416196.84999999998 411811.95000000001
Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 419726.59999999998 421968.40000000002
```

Is there anyway to get this console output to be exported somewhere so that I can see exactly where/what the errors are?

Ideally, I would like this information to be added to the filtered layer as a new field.

Comment: Use ST_IsValidReason in your query https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: I get:

ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare(select * from '2001 Census Data' WHERE not ST_IsValidReason(geometry)):
  no such function: ST_IsValidReason

Comment: Too old SpatiaLite then. Gets complicated, probably you would need to compile from trunk https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/brlist.